# In Android Project :- In my application there are lots of images, i have to verify them, How can i use Assertion

Tags: android, automation, robotium

In Robotium :- I am writing automation scripts using Solo class. Now i have to verify the images in my application.

For **texts** we can use `Assert.assertTrue(solo.searchText("rtf"));`

For **images**, is there any command in Robotium Solo Class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. Most suggested way to *test* (its meaning may vary) ImageViews is given by:

- In code under test, set something in the ImageView tag that you want to check later. E.g. the drawable resource Id.
- In test code, get whatever you set in the tag, and verify it has the expected value.

Also, you may want to have a look at [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robotium-developers/m43FrtHZ-IA) on some other method to visually check the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
assertTrue(solo.getCurrentActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo).isVisible());
```

For more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26114862