# How to check from Robotium that my png is present on the screen?

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, robotium

I create an additional method:

```
public boolean exampleEdTxt1(){
 try{
  solo.getCurrentActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.action_drw);
  return true;
 }
 catch(AssertionError e){
  return false;
 }
}
```

But, when test is runing, code

```
assertTrue(exampleEdTxt1());
```

always returns success and code

```
assertFalse(exampleEdTxt1());
```

always returns fail.

How to check from Robotium that my png is present on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

try using .isShown()

```
solo.getCurrentActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.action_drw).isShown();
```

this assert i used to check if my image is displayed:

```
assertEquals(true, solo.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(R.id.getting_started_image_1).isShown());
```

hope it helps

Here i check for imageView

```
Boolean isVisible = (Boolean) solo.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView1).isShown();
        assertTrue(isVisible);
```

Here is to check for drawable (image)

```
Boolean isVisible2 = (Boolean) solo.getCurrentActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image).isVisible();
        assertTrue(isVisible2);
```

imageView from the xml i used:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="186dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method fails.

"isShown()" IDE highlights in red with the message: "Cannot resolve method 'isShown()'".

Although I am successfully using the code:

assertTrue(solo.getView(R.id.action_search).isShown());

But if I try to check:

assertEquals(false,getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edit_btn).isVisible());

test falls on this line with an error: expected: but was:

Comment: For 
Boolean isVisible2 = (Boolean) solo.getCurrentActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image).isVisible();
code
assertTrue(isVisible2); - always returns success (Even if there is no drawable on the screen) and code
assertFalse(isVisible2); - always returns fail.

Comment: Drawable.isVisible() method return internal state of visibility (when you explicitly say imageView.setVisible(true), true is what you get) but does not check id drawable is shown on screen.

Answer (score 0):

For

```
Boolean isVisible2 = (Boolean) solo.getCurrentActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image).isVisible();
```

code

```
assertTrue(isVisible2);
```

always returns success (Even if there is no drawable on the screen) and code

```
assertFalse(isVisible2);
```

always returns fail.